# HttpWebRequest initializing - response never received

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, windows-phone-7, httpwebresponse

I am currently working on an implementation of an application for Windows Phone 7 that should retrieve the SHOUTcast stream (inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734843/httpwebrequest-for-shoutcast-on-windows-phone7/3743113#3743113)). The stream location is represented by an IP address and a port.

Here is an example of a SHOUTcast stream URL:
http://78.159.104.183:80

I am trying to make a **HttpWebRequest** to get the data from the stream:

`HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://78.159.104.183:80")`;

Once the request is initialized, I am trying to get a response via an asynchronous callback:

```
request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetShoutAsync), request);
```

GetShoutAsync looks like this:

```
void GetShoutAsync(IAsyncResult res)
{
     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)res.AsyncState;
     HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(res);
}
```

When I build the project and run it, it gets to the point where the request is initialized, but the callback is **never called**.

I noticed an interesting thing - SHOUTcast implements a technique by which when the user tries to navigate to the stream URL, the server detects the user agent and if it is a web browser, it will simply show a HTML page instead of passing **application/octet-stream** content.

You can still receive the stream directly if you use a slash and semicolon at the end of the stream URL: http://78.159.104.183:80/;

However, in my application, I cannot get the response - the callback seems to never be reached. I tried faking the user agent by passing it directly to the HttpWebRequest:

```
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; it-IT; rv:1.9.0.2) Gecko/2008092313 Ubuntu/9.25 (jaunty) Firefox/3.8";
```

This works for the simple stream URL (without the semicolon at the end) to get the HTML contents, but I cannot get the binary stream.

Anyone ever encountered something like this or knows what's causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea if this would work for you but I had the same problem,

and explicitly setting

request.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;
request.Method = "GET";

seemed to whatever reason get my callback to fire...

I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to switch on [UseUnsafeHeaderParsing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.configuration.httpwebrequestelement.useunsafeheaderparsing%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), given the flakey nature of Shoutcast *"HTTP"*.

Does your code work when you turn it onto normal web pages?

EDIT

This looks like an excellent lead: Perhaps you need to set [`AllowReadStreamBuffering`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowreadstreambuffering%28VS.95%29.aspx) to false:

> The `AllowReadStreamBuffering` property affects when the callback from `BeginGetResponse`  method is called. When the `AllowReadStreamBuffering`  property is `true`, the callback is raised once the entire stream has been downloaded into memory. When the `AllowReadStreamBuffering` property is `false`, the callback is raised as soon as the stream is available for reading which may be before all data has arrived.

The default setting for [`AllowReadStreamBuffering`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowreadstreambuffering%28VS.95%29.aspx) is `true`. This means you'll never hit the callback, because the download never ends (and left for long enough, you'll probably run out of memory). Set it to `false`.

Comment: Yes, it works for normal web pages. On a side note, UseUnsafeHeaderParsing is not available on Windows Phone 7.

Comment: No exceptions? Supposing you try the synchronous counterparts for WebRequest? Does it just hang?

Comment: No exceptions at all. And no, it doesn't hang the applications - it just never executes the code inside the callback.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if you do things synchronously rather than async with callback, does the code hang, throw or proceed? It might lend a clue as to where the problem lies in the async version.

Comment: For Windows Phone 7 applications, you cannot download data synchronously via WebRequest or HttpWebRequest - only async calls are available.

Comment: Does your code work if you execute it in a desktop (PC) ? If you can repro it on the desktop, can you take a system.net tracelog and see why the callback is not being invoked? See http://ferozedaud.blogspot.com/2009/08/tracing-with-systemnet.html on how to create the tracelog. Typically, callback should be invoked if the response was received by the app.

Comment: I see. WinPhone7 uses the Silverlight API, so no sync methods. I updated my answer with a good lead.

Comment: AllowWriteStreamBuffering only applies for uploading data (by calling write on the stream returned by GetRequestStream()). It is not clear if upload is being used here.