# Asynchronous HTTP calls in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, webclient

I'd like to make a request to a server, parse the response, and carry on with my app. It never seems to get to the callback method, and I'm pretty sure that when I call send(a_url) this thing doesn't even execute the HTTP request at all.

```
public class item
{
    public status status { get; set; }
    public response response { get; set; }
}
public class status
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
public class response
{
    public string token { get; set; }
    public int distance { get; set; }
    public int angle { get; set; }
}

...

    public item deserializedJSON;

...

    /* sends the url string to the server */
    public void send(string url)
    {
        WebClient c = new WebClient();

// EDIT: Swapped the next two lines\
        c.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCompleted);
        c.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));


    }

    /* parses the JSON response from the server */
    public void DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
            deserializedJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<item>(e.Result);
            isReady = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wire-up the event **before** you call the method!

```
public void send(string url)
{
    WebClient c = new WebClient();
    c.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCompleted);
    c.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
}
```

Comment: Ha, yeah, should have. Good call. I've rearranged it but it's still never setting my deserializedJSON var.

Comment: Do you get any exception at all (like a timeout)?

Answer (score 0):

You might try attaching the event handler before you order the download.

Answer (score 0):

The event can be wired after the download call - it will work correctly. Did you set breakpoints inside the event handler to make sure that it really never hits it? Where and how are you calling the `send` method?

A similar issue was tied to `HttpWebRequest` (details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746629/httpwebrequest-initializing-response-never-received)) - for some reason it can be tied to the data you are downloading. Care to share the URL?

Comment: It is conceivable that the DownloadStringAsync call could have completed before the DownloadStringCompleted delegate was attached. (Although very unlikely for a web request, I agree.)

Comment: Given the case, I highly doubt the delay in wiring the event is the cause - there seems to be a data problem from what I see.